# Remove level in nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I have the following nested dictionary:

```
dictionary = {(0,'AAPL'): {0: {'v': 55478991.0,
                               'vw': 145.868,
                               'o': 146.83,
                               'c': 145.31,
                               'h': 147.2285,
                               'l': 145.01,
                               't': 1677646800000,
                               'n': 461613}}}
```

My problem is that there is one "level" too many. Essentially, I would like to assign the value of the middle dictionary to the key of the outermost dictionary, in order to achieve the following result:

```
dictionary = {(0,'AAPL'): {'v': 55478991.0,
                           'vw': 145.868,
                           'o': 146.83,
                           'c': 145.31,
                           'h': 147.2285,
                           'l': 145.01,
                           't': 1677646800000,
                           'n': 461613}}
```

Ultimately, I have a collection of multiple such dictionaries that I need to modify. The key of the middle dictionary is always the same, but the key of the outermost dictionary will always be different. E.g.:

```
{(0,'LHDX'): {0: {'v': 194946367.0,
   'vw': 1.123,
   'o': 1.04,
   'c': 0.7901,
   'h': 1.45,
   'l': 0.7321,
   't': 1677646800000,
   'n': 373039}},
 (1,'LHDX'): {0: {'v': 45745084.0,
   'vw': 0.6214,
   'o': 0.7133,
   'c': 0.56,
   'h': 0.7496,
   'l': 0.5156,
   't': 1677733200000,
   'n': 61922}},
 (2,'BBBY'): {0: {'v': 38914452.0,
   'vw': 1.4392,
   'o': 1.53,
   'c': 1.39,
   'h': 1.54,
   'l': 1.39,
   't': 1678078800000,
   'n': 77211}}}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Will you ever have `{(0,'AAPL'): {0: {...}, 1: {...}}}` or any other dictionaries in there? If so, how should they be handled? IN other words, does your middle dict always have only one value?

Comment: Will the inner dicts always come wilth their key equal to `0` ? If you provide more examples of your data we could help you generalize instead of giving you a solution to this specific case

Comment: The inner dicts will alway have a key equal to 0, but key for outer dict will always be different. I updated my post to provide more context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have clarified your question:

```
dictionary = {(0,'LHDX'): {0: {'v': 194946367.0,
   'vw': 1.123,
   'o': 1.04,
   'c': 0.7901,
   'h': 1.45,
   'l': 0.7321,
   't': 1677646800000,
   'n': 373039}},
 (1,'LHDX'): {0: {'v': 45745084.0,
   'vw': 0.6214,
   'o': 0.7133,
   'c': 0.56,
   'h': 0.7496,
   'l': 0.5156,
   't': 1677733200000,
   'n': 61922}},
 (2,'BBBY'): {0: {'v': 38914452.0,
   'vw': 1.4392,
   'o': 1.53,
   'c': 1.39,
   'h': 1.54,
   'l': 1.39,
   't': 1678078800000,
   'n': 77211}}}
```

You can do:

```
dictionary = {k:v[0] for k,v in dictionary.items()}
```

Output

```
{(0, 'LHDX'): {'v': 194946367.0,
  'vw': 1.123,
  'o': 1.04,
  'c': 0.7901,
  'h': 1.45,
  'l': 0.7321,
  't': 1677646800000,
  'n': 373039},
 (1, 'LHDX'): {'v': 45745084.0,
  'vw': 0.6214,
  'o': 0.7133,
  'c': 0.56,
  'h': 0.7496,
  'l': 0.5156,
  't': 1677733200000,
  'n': 61922},
 (2, 'BBBY'): {'v': 38914452.0,
  'vw': 1.4392,
  'o': 1.53,
  'c': 1.39,
  'h': 1.54,
  'l': 1.39,
  't': 1678078800000,
  'n': 77211}}
```

Comment: This addresses my problem perfectly, thank you very much for your answer!